# When localStorage is null, why does it still work like it has keys and values?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I write some simple code shows a picture, and let the pictures moves from the left to the right then to the left forever. I use localStorage to let it remember the picture's location upon page load.

There is nothing wrong about the code.

What confused me is after I clear all the keys stored in the localStorage, my code still works like before(it still remember the picture's location upon page load).

Below is the code, and the console.log shows that localStorage is null.

My question is when localStorage has been cleared, how does it work like it has keys and values. What is the logic here?

```
<img style="position:absolute;" src="Cat Walk.gif">

<script>

var img = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
img.style.left = '0px';

var walkForwards;

function catWalk() {
    var currentLeft = parseInt(img.style.left);

    if(walkForwards === 'true' && (currentLeft > (window.innerWidth-img.width))) {
        walkForwards = 'false';
    }
    if(walkForwards === 'false' && (currentLeft <= 0)) {
        walkForwards = 'true';
    }

    if(walkForwards === 'true') {
        img.style.left = (currentLeft + 10) + 'px';
    }
    else{
        img.style.left = (currentLeft - 10) + 'px';
    }
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('currentLoc'), localStorage.getItem('direc'));
}

window.setInterval(catWalk, 50);

window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    localStorage.setItem('currentLoc', img.style.left);
    localStorage.setItem('direc', walkForwards);
};

img.style.left = localStorage.getItem('currentLoc');
walkForwards = localStorage.getItem('direc');

localStorage.clear();

</script>
```

Comment: It's not clear what's wrong or whats intended in your code. Can you explain a little more?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with my code. It's a simple code shows a picture, and the pictures moves from the left to the right then to the left forever. I use localStorage to let the pictures stays where is was(remember the pictures location) when reload. My question is if localStorage didn't have any value after clear, why my code still works like before?

Comment: What is the `window.onbeforeunload` trying to achieve?

Comment: You ran `localStorage.clear()` after setting `img.style.left` and `walkForwards`. Then the timer fired, `catWalk` was called, and it couldn’t find anything because you cleared the localStorage.

Comment: @Ryan You're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a user goes to the page having the last values saved,

```
img.style.left = localStorage.getItem('currentLoc');
walkForwards = localStorage.getItem('direc');
```

correctly loads them. Then, they get deleted by

```
localStorage.clear();
```

From now on, whenever you console.log the items from localStorage, they will be unset, i.e. the call to getItem will return `null`.

But when the user reloads, closes the tab, or leaves the page, the then-current values get saved again:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    localStorage.setItem('currentLoc', img.style.left);
    localStorage.setItem('direc', walkForwards);
};
```

Therefore, they are available upon next page load.